# Teamcity not loading environment variables - Fortify automation

Tags: batch-file, teamcity, fortify

I have *Teamcity* currently setup to run a batch file, this batch file executes a fortify scan.  It seems the environment variable 'PATH' had loaded correctly on one attempt and started to perform the scan.  On the next build attempt the batch file couldn't locate one of the executable(`sourceanalyzer.exe`). When looking into the user defined parameters it seems different environment variables were loaded than the previous build attempt.  It looks like the system environment variables load on the successful attempt and then a users environment variable loaded on the failed attempt.  Is there a way to permanently set the environment variable **PATH** in the agent to load only the system environment variables?

**UPDATE:**

I have tried several things, to include passing in a *Fortify* environment variable, which does allow TeamCity to start running the scan.  However, it looks like I hit another snag with Fortify's plugin for vs2015.  The new error states it cannot find the plugin. I assume this is because pathways are hard coded? Seeing as TeamCity doesn't use the System environment variables and I have to pass them in for TeamCity to find these directories. Is there an easier way to use the batch file to load the system environment variables to avoid hard coding pathways?  Would `setlocal` in the batch file help load these system environment variables, so I can just call `sourceanalyzer` with out creating environment variables or hard coding pathways?

Comment: Are you sure the builds are running on the same agent? This smells of agent differences to me.

Comment: @sferencik Yes, they are running on the same agent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIRC, Teamcity will ask you if you want to install the build agent on the `System` account or the user account.  By default it selects the `System` account and as long as you aren't running any GUI apps, you won't notice the difference... until something like this happens.  If `Fortify` is GUI based, then reinstall your build agent on the user account and ignore the following. Otherwise...

When you set your `PATH` variables using the System(Control Panel) advanced settings, there are two panes, one for user and one for system.  Here you can inspect the `System` variables to make sure they are correct.

What I will generally do is create a new key, say `FORTIFY_PATH`and prepend `%FORTIFY_PATH%` to the `System` `PATH` variable.  THEN RESTART YOUR MACHINE.  The path won't get updated correctly until you do.

Next, login to the system account using PSExec: https://superuser.com/a/596395 and try to run your tools from that command prompt to verify that they are working in the build agent's environment.  I once had trouble getting an SVN script to upload until I logged into the `System` account and provided my SVN password.  Some settings are stored in %APPDATA% which is different from the user account.

If you can't get `Fortify` to run from the `System` command prompt, then you should probably reinstall your build agent to your user account. Or install Fortify to the System account (if possible).

When configuring TeamCity build agents, check the agent system and environment variables By going to `Agents->Agent->Agent Parameters`, or the `/agentDetails.html?id=1&tab=agentParameters&kind=env`path on your server.

After changing the parameters, restart the agent or restart the agent's machine.

Comment: Thanks for your response! The correct environment variable is listed in `System` account.  I also was able to get sourceanalyzer to run using PSExec, but it looks like %APPDATA% is pointing to the wrong fortify and  plugin versions.  Is there a way to update the %APPDATA% for the system to point to the new version?

Comment: **DO NOT** change `%APPDATA%` to point somewhere else.  I mean, unless you really don't like that machine anymore.  See if you can install Fortify onto the system account or reinstall the build agent onto your user account.